# how to split string by reading text from file

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception, split

I am trying to read os-release file on Linux and trying to get the OS version by finding VERSION_ID="12.3" line. I wrote below piece of code but at the last after splitting the string first time I am unable to go further. I reached up to splitting to "12.3" from VERSION_ID, after this I applied split function again and getting "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0" error. , Need your help and valuable suggestions.

```
File fobj2 = new File("C:\\os-release");
if(fobj2.exists() && !fobj2.isDirectory())
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fobj2);
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
     String line = sc.nextLine();
     //VERSION_ID="12.3"
     if(line.contains("VERSION_ID="))
     {
     System.out.println(" VERSION_ID= " + line );
     String [] ver = line.split("=");
     if(ver.length > 1)
     {
         String [] ver_id = line.split("=");
         System.out.println(" ver_id.length " + ver_id.length );
         System.out.println(" ver_id[0] " + ver_id[0] );
         System.out.println(" ver_id[1] " + ver_id[1] );
         System.out.println(" ver_id[1].length() " + ver_id[1].length() );
                     
         String [] FinalVer1 = ver_id[1].split(".");

         System.out.println(" FinalVer1[1].length() " + FinalVer1[1].length() );
         System.out.println(" FinalVer1[1] " + FinalVer1[1] );
     }
     }                   
}
```

Comment: This is rather messy. I'd suggest you try to narrow your problem down to just one or two lines of code that is the actual problem / exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is yet another way to gather the Major and Minor version values from the line String:

```
String line = "VERSION_ID=\"12.3\"";
    
// Bring line to lowercase to eliminate possible letter case 
// variations (if any) then see if 'version-id' is in the line:
if (line.toLowerCase().contains("version_id")) {
    // Remove all whitespaces and double-quotes from line then
    // split the line regardless of whether or not there are
    // whitespaces before or after the '=' character.
    String version = line.replaceAll("[ \"]", "").split("\\s*=\\s*")[1];
    //Get version Major.
    String major = version.split("[.]")[0];
    // Get version Minor.
    String minor = version.split("[.]")[1];
    
    // Display contents of all variables
    System.out.println("Line:     --> " + line);
    System.out.println("Version:  --> " + version);
    System.out.println("Major:    --> " + major);
    System.out.println("Minor:    --> " + minor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
File fobj2 = new File("C:\\os-release");
if(fobj2.exists() && !fobj2.isDirectory())
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fobj2);
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
     String line = sc.nextLine();
     //VERSION_ID="12.3"
     if(line.contains("VERSION_ID="))
     {
     System.out.println(" VERSION_ID= " + line );
     String [] ver = line.split("=");
     if(ver.length > 1)
     {
         String [] ver_id = line.split("=");
         System.out.println(" ver_id.length " + ver_id.length );
         System.out.println(" ver_id[0] " + ver_id[0] );
         System.out.println(" ver_id[1] " + ver_id[1] );
         System.out.println(" ver_id[1].length() " + ver_id[1].length() );
             
         // Here        
         String [] FinalVer1 = ver_id[1].split("\\.");

         System.out.println(" FinalVer1[1].length() " + FinalVer1[1].length() );
         System.out.println(" FinalVer1[1] " + FinalVer1[1] );
     }
     }                   
}
```

Just need to escape the dot like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when You are using split method on string like "VERSION_ID="12.3"", the output would be: String arr = {"VERSION_ID", "12.3"}. So why are You using the next split with "=" on the ver_id array. Try using ".", from my understanding You are looking for number after the dot.